# Removing and Adding Rows in a JTable using AbstractTableModel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, abstracttablemodel

I have a serious problem, removing rows from my JTable, my code is the same as what I saw when I tried to learn AbstractTableModel:

```
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

             boolean DEBUG = true;

            input_Data input = new input_Data();
            String[] columnNames = {"First Name",
                      "Last Name",
                      "Sport",
                      "# of Years",
                      "Vegetarian"};
            Object[][] data = {
                {"Kathy", "Smith",
                    "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)},
                {"John", "Doe",
                        "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)},
                {"Sue", "Black",
                            "Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false)},
                {"Jane", "White",
                                "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
                {"Joe", "Brown",
                                    "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false)};


                    public int getColumnCount() {
                        return columnNames.length;                  
                    }

                    public int getRowCount() {
                        return data.length;
                    }

                    public String getColumnName(int col) {
                        return columnNames[col];
                    }

                    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
                        return data[row][col];
                    }
                    public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
                        return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
                    }


                    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {

                        if (col < 2) {
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                    public void removeRow(Row)
                    {

                       fireTableRowsDeleted(Row,Row);

                    }
                }
```

But the problem is that nothing happens when I call removeRow!!
I think that maybe I should edit data too, but how? 
I am new to java and I really got stock into this problem...

Comment: Use the `DefaultTableModel`. It supports a removeRow() method already.

Comment: I cann't, I need a check box in my table, so I cann't use DefaultTableModel

Comment: There is not reason you can't use a DefaultTableModel for that. You just store a Boolean value in the TableModel and override the `getColumnClass(...)` method to return Boolean and the table will choose an appropriate renderer. There is no reason to create a completely new class just to override a single method of the class.

Comment: thanks a lot my problem solved :)

Answer (score 3):

You've not actually removed anything with this code. Don't use a 2-D array for your data nucleus. Use an `ArrayList<CustomType>` for the data nucleus of this class, actually **remove** the row of data from this List within your `removeRow(int row)` method, and then call the `fireTableRowsDeleted(...)` method.